# working with multiple table, php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having 2 tables, where in one table i am storing documents type(which is dynamically created) and in other i am saving revisions for the documents type when a new revision is released for it.
Tables eg:

TABLE 1

```
Doc Type
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

TABLE 2

```
Doc Type    REV   DATE
AAA         A     10-04-2013
BBB         A     10-04-2013
CCC         A     10-04-2013
AAA         B     18-04-2013
CCC         C     18-04-2013
BBB         C     25-04-2013
DDD         A     06-05-2013
```

Now i want to query b/w 2 tables for each document type in table 1 with documents type & revision in table 2 & get result in HTML Table format with the latest version(s) available.
Here is my desired output:

Result

```
Doc Type    Rev-1   Rev-2   Rev-3   Rev-4
AAA         A       B       B       B
BBB         A       C       C       C
CCC         A       A       D       D
DDD         --NA--  --NA--  --NA--  A
```

Can anybody help me in achieving this...

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Please explain what are the rules to get the desired output from your sample data. Right now it doesn't match and make any sense to me. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Simply telling whenever there is new Revision type added, i should get the latest Revision for the doc type along with previous revisions if any.

Comment: that means if a document has 100 revisions, you need 100(+1) columns to be returned? your expected result does not make sense to me, i cannot understand any logic. why AAA's B revision takes 3 columns? You are just padding dynamic generated columns with data? Your specific desired output has too many flaws.

Comment: How can you explain a row for `DDD` in the result based on your sample data? Why `A` is `rev-4`?

Comment: If you please refer to my Result table, you can see that in Rev-2 Revision for only "AAA" & "BBB" has changed but not "CCC". But the output shows latest AVAILABLE revisions for each document type available.

Comment: Hi Peterm, In case of DDD, it is another Document added for the product later on which was not added initially while creating matrix. The newly added document was released as say "A" and was added to matrix..

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to have the SQL code you used to create the tables, but you probably you need to use JOIN, something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM document 
JOIN revision ON document.id = revision.document_id
WHERE document.id = 1
```

(Replace "1" with the real id, escaping it from PHP if needed.)

Take care that this will give you a row for each revision, I think the format you want (a variable number of columns) it's not possible with SQL (but you can use PHP for the output formatting).

Comment: HI, Thanks for the reply, This i had done using ("SELECT * FROM documents_table WHERE EXISTS (SELECT doc_type FROM doc_type_table WHERE documents_table.document_type = '".$row['doc_type']."')"). i get output like this:PCR B D E
WL A C
PL
DRAWING

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve using the EXIST clause. I think you need to join the two tables you have using a syntax similar than the one on the answer. My advice is to start using the code I provided in phpmyadmin or mysql cli just replacing the table names with yours.

Comment: Can you paste a sample of the result you get with my code, and the result you are expecting?